# Accessing full user data in the Facebook graph API with facebook php sdk

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've created a demo link which I hope to embed in a FB page. When a user clicks on this link they are presented with a permissions page saying if they proceed further then I can collect certain information about them. I require their bio, likes, films, books etc data. At the minute, when they click "proceed" I'm only able to collect the following information:

ID
Name
Gender

Note the app used when in this process is a user app with full privilledges.

Interestingly, if I add the user as owner of the app and then send them the link then when they click it I collect full data. The question I have - is there a way of fully collecting all the data of a user in facebook without adding them as an owner of the app? I know the graph API is such that it is easy for pages but users seem to be different! Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most permissions need to get reviewed, or they will only work for users with a role in the App. Read all about Login Review in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review